# python logging - how do I truncate the pathname to just the last few characters or just the filename?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I'm using python logging and I have a formatter that looks like the following:

```
formatter = logging.Formatter(
    '%(asctime)s - %(pathname)86s - %(lineno)4s - %(message)s', '%d %H:%M'
    )
```

As you can see, I like the information in my log files to line up neatly in columns.  The reason I have 86 spaces reserved for the pathname is because the full paths to some of the files used in my program are that long.  However, all I really need is the actual file name, not the full path.  How can I get the logging module to give me just the file name?  Better yet, since I have some long filenames, I'd like the first 3 characters of the filename, followed by '~', then the last 16 characters.  So

```
/Users/Jon/important_dir/dev/my_project/latest/testing-tools/test_read_only_scenarios_happily.py
```

should become

```
tes~arios_happily.py
```

Comment: I saw your edit suggestion; glad you worked it out. `record.args` is either a dict or a tuple, but your formatter suggested that you were using a dict exclusively, which is why I created my solution based on that. It's easy enough to adapt to a tuple too, as you discovered. :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll have to implement your own Formatter subclass that truncates the path for you; the formatting string cannot do this.

Since you want to use just the *filename* you'd want to use the `filename` parameter as the base, which we can then truncate as needed.

For the size-limited version, I'd actually use a *new* record attribute for, leaving the existing `filename` to be the full name. Lets call it `filename20`.

```
import logging

class FilenameTruncatingFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        # truncate the filename if it is longer than 20 characters
        filename = record.filename
        if len(filename) > 20:
            filename = '{}~{}'.format(filename[:3], filename[-16:])
        record.filename20 = filename
        return super(PathTruncatingFormatter, self).format(record)
```

Use this class instead of the normal `logging.Formatter` instance, and reference the `filename20` field in the formatting string:

```
formatter = FilenameTruncatingFormatter(
    '%(asctime)s - %(filename20)20s - %(lineno)4s - %(message)s', '%d %H:%M'
)
```

Note that I also shortened the space needed for the field to 20 characters: `%(...)20s`.

If you have to specify the formatter in a [ConfigParser-style configuration file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#configuration-file-format), create a named formatter via a `[formatter_NAME]`  section, and give that section a `class` key:

```ini
[formatter_truncated]
class=some.module.FilenameTruncatingFormatter
format=%(asctime)s - %(filename20)20s - %(lineno)4s - %(message)s
datefmt=%d %H:%M
```

and then you can use `formatter=truncated` in any handler sections you define.

For the [dictionary-schema style configuration](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#dictionary-schema-details), the same applies: specify the formatter class via the `class` key in any formatter definition.

Comment: Is there a way to do this if i am using logging.ini file ?

Comment: @SouravPrem: no, because you can't define a custom class in `logging.ini`.

Comment: @SouravPrem: I see that you can now use a `class` key in the `.ini` style configuration format, so I can now state that you can do this in a `logging.ini` file by specifying where to import the custom `PathTruncatingFormatter` class from. I've added this to the answer.

Comment: This doesn't work for my. It can't find the module I put for `class=` and if I do fully qualified path for my class I get a circular import error.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use filename instead of pathname. Refer https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/logging.html#formatter-objects for more details

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
import os

def shorten_filename(filename):
    f = os.path.split(filename)[1]
    return "%s~%s" % (f[:3], f[-16:]) if len(f) > 19 else f
```

Comment: Minor nit, I'd use `len(f) > 20`, since the shortened file name will  have 20 characters anyway (19 taken from the file name plus the tilde).

Comment: Thanks.  However, this answer doesn't address the problem in the context of the logging module.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3: Same but different, but thought I would share, I simply wanted the last two things in the path, The directory and the file name.

```
class MyFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        if 'pathname' in record.__dict__.keys():
            sections = record.pathname.split("/")
            sec_len = len(sections)
            record.pathname = "{}/{}".format(sections[sec_len - 2], sections[sec_len - 1])
        return super(MyFormatter, self).format(record)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is the Python 3 version of the same which @Martijn had written. As @Nick pointed out, the **record** parameter passed is a LogRecord object in Python 3.

```
import logging
import os

class PathTruncatingFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        if 'pathname' in record.__dict__.keys():
            # truncate the pathname
            filename = os.path.basename(record.pathname)
            if len(filename) > 20:
                filename = '{}~{}'.format(filename[:3], filename[-16:])
            record.pathname = filename
        return super(PathTruncatingFormatter, self).format(record)
```

Answer (score 0):

## For python 3.8 and above :

Same than response from @Glen Bizeau but in a more compact and tuneable way, allowing to set the number of maximum parent folders displayed :

```py
class FileFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    MAX_FOLDERS = 4

    def format(self, record):
        if 'pathname' in record.__dict__.keys():
            if (sec_len := len(sections := record.pathname.split(os.path.sep))) > self.MAX_FOLDERS :
                record.pathname = "(...)" + os.path.sep.join([sections[sec_len - i] for i in reversed(range(1,self.MAX_FOLDERS+1))])
        return super().format(record)
```

Yields: `(...)__packages__\Inflow\ios\load.py`
instead of: `C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Python\__packages__\Inflow\ios\load.py`